# Cannot start cron service

Tags: 14.04, cron, services

On an ubuntu 14.04 running on docker, I have a problem with the cron service, doing "start cron", "status cron", "restart cron", etc.. do nothing, if I type ps -aux there is no cron process running.

(doing apt-get install cron tell me that the package is already a the newest version)

Any idea ? Thanks!

Comment: Docker is the wrong tool if you want to run services other than your main process. For one, there is not init system running which can start or stop services.

Comment: But I have other environment running on ubuntu 16 who can run cron without any problem, so..?

Comment: And how did you set up that environment?

Comment: Using the phusion/baseimage, doing an apt-get update / full-upgrade, copying the cron to the docker image in the Dockerfile (the same process for both of them, i'm using ubuntu 14.04 because on this one i'm using PHP 5.6 instead of PHP7)

Comment: "copying the cron to the docker"?

Comment: on the host i'm doing a git pull, the git project contain the cron I want to run on the docker image

Comment: Looks like this https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker thing implements its own init system. You should file a bug report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
apt-get install rsyslog
```

and executing `rsyslog` did solve my problem.